# Object within an object is null

Tags: c#, .net, nested

I'm using C# and have created an object to send to a JSON service that looks like this:

```
public class SendRequest
{
    public string id { get; set; }
    public string case { get; set; }
    public string method { get; set; }
    public Volume value { get; set; } 
}

public class Volume
{
    public int level;
    public bool mute;
}
```

I can code hint when setting the sub object:

```
var _req = new SendRequest();
_req.value.mute = false;
_req.value.level = 50;
```

But when the program is run, the sub-object itself is null  (_req.value = null) and the two items under that object don't show.

Why is this happening?

Comment: you haven't created an instance of a Volume object so it doesn't exist

Comment: You need to assign a new `Volume` object to `value`.

Comment: Could you show your json?

Comment: you never initialize value to something also change your property `case` to `Case` `case` is a reserved word

Comment: Thanks, momentary lapse of reason.  For some reason I thought that created a new SendRequest would also create a new Volume object.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to initialize the "value" to something.

Add this constructor to your SendRequest class:

```
public SendRequest(){ value = new Volume(); }
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [object initializers](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384062.aspx)

```
var _req = new SendRequest()
{
    value = new Volume()
    {
        mute = false,
        level = 50,
    },
};
```

Answer (score -1):

at this point method is null

```
public string method { get; set; }
```

longer but what you can do is

```
private string method = string.empty;
public string Method { get {return method;} set {method = value;} }
```

value is just a bad name

```
private Volume volume = new Volume();
public Volume Volume { get {return volume;} set {volume = value;} }
```

or

```
volume = new Volume (mute = false, value.level = 50);
```

Comment: @dotctor A variable is null until initialized.  So I need to spell it out with volume?

Comment: the whole concept you are trying to show can be shown just by a comment: "A variable is null until initialized", I think the whole answer you have provided here just misleads and confuses the OP.

Comment: @dotctor OK that is how you feel.  Thank you for your input.  I think your solution is not as good as it need to be repeated in the case of multiple constructors.